# Does License check response needs further obfuscation to make it more secure?

Tags: java, android

I have created an android app which is a paid app.The app utilizes google's licensing verification library for the license checks and implementing ServerManagedPolicy in it.  As the ServerManagedPolicy caches the license response data from the server with obfuscation in SharedPreferences,  do I need to implement any further obfuscation method to make the cached response data more secure and tamper proof?

Comment: Google employs an army of PhD's.  If they already have a security process in place that does this, I would trust it before I trusted my own judgement, as neither you or I have the necessary expertise to do it well.  Never write your own security algorithm when a pre-existing, well-known algorithm already does it better than you can.

Answer (score 1):

Answer **No** to "*Does X need obfuscation to make it more secure?*" for any given **X**

If you want something to *really* be more secure, obfuscation won't provide it.

Comment: While you are right, I don't think we should get stuck on the word "obfuscation" here. The real question, in my opinion, is if the cashing of the response data is a vulnerability and if so how it can be fixed.